# Proper Time Span Punctuation On The Hour Times

Tags: grammar, time

Curious as to if a colon is needed when typing on the hour times. Example:
9:00 a.m.-10:00 a.m. or 9-10 a.m. or 9:00-10:00a.m. Would love references if you have them!

Comment: I don't know that there's a standard for displaying it as you're wanting to. I can say that the best thing to do--if you have multiple hours--is to maintain __consistency__ between all your hour ranges. If you've one time that starts at the half hour, always using colons would be preferable, but the meaning is clear regardless. The only other help I can offer is to use an en-dash (vs. hyphen) to indicate ranges.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ISO standard [(8601)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) {or [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm) if you are prepared to pay} which defines formats for the exchange of date and time data. In that standard there are two acceptable formats for times, namely the *basic* hhmmss and the *extended* hh:mm:ss.

This means that **four seconds after a quarter to five PM** can be written as **164504** or as **16:45:04**. Either is fine when data is being transferred electronically as the receiving system should understand both standards. However a human reading the basic format would probably think **"One hundred and sixty four thousand five hundred and four what?"**, whereas reading the extended format they would probably think **"Just after quarter to four"**

The use of colons may not be absolutely compulsory but, if you don't use them, you probably won't be understood properly; and that, after all, is the purpose of communication.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your style guide. If you're not following a style guide you can do whatever you want; just pick your favorite style and be consistent.

As an example, [APA](http://journalistsresource.org/tip-sheets/style/ap-style-basics) (emphasis mine):

> Time: Use lowercase a.m. and p.m., with periods. Always use figures, with a space between the time and the a.m. or p.m.: “By 6:30 a.m. she was long gone.” **If it’s an exact hour, no “:00″ is required.** If a time range is entirely in the morning or evening, use a.m. or p.m. only once: “6:30-10 p.m.” If it goes from the morning into the evening (or vice versa), you need both: “10 a.m.-2 p.m.”